# join 2 tables and return multiple rows in LINQ

Tags: join

We have two tables.Equipment_Table and PicturesOfEquipment_Table.
I would like to table the details of the equipment, and the second table photo to return equipment.
Equipment_Table :EqID , TitleOfEquipment , Comment
PicturesOfEquipment_Table : PicID , EqID , PictureName
Function is :

```
public List<object> Return_Equipment(long GroupCode)
    {
        var td = from s in Entity.Equipment_Table 
                 join r in Entity.PicturesOfEquipment_Table on s.EqID equals r.EqID 
                 where s.ServiceGroupCode == GroupCode
                 select s;


        return td.ToList();
    }
```

but td.ToList() The error occurs.
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Answer (score 0):

Just make:

```
public List<object> Return_Equipment(long GroupCode)
    {
        var td = from s in Entity.Equipment_Table 
                 join r in Entity.PicturesOfEquipment_Table on s.EqID equals r.EqID 
                 where s.ServiceGroupCode == GroupCode
                 select s;


        return td;
    }
```